# Resource for learning analysis of sequence data via QIIME 2

Tags: bioinformatics, book-recommendation, microbiome

I am trying to study/learn metagenomics through 16s rRNA microbial data and I want to teach myself/review core biology concepts while also learning the QIIME 2 analysis pipeline, as the website suggests learning it instead of QIIME for beginners.

I found a great source : http://www.science.smith.edu/cmbs/wp-content/uploads/sites/36/2015/09/Tutorial-from-sample-to-analyzed-data-using-Qiime-for-analysis.pdf
but was hoping for something with an analysis I could actually work through on my own, as this one involves the use of a cluster, where as I only have access to a laptop of moderate power and also one that involves QIIME 2.

Also something free and maybe as hand-holding as possible would be ideal too.

As for the platform I am learning on, it is a virtual box instance of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QIIME 2 tutorials are the place to get started - see [here](https://docs.qiime2.org/2017.8/getting-started/).

Comment: So do you think those tutorials could take someone from layman to decent? I read on your profile that you teach bioinformatics so I am willing to take any other advice too. Thanks

Comment: They will teach you QIIME 2 without assuming much background knowledge. If you're new to the idea of studying microbiomes, you'll probably want some other resources too, possibly including [Gut Check](https://www.coursera.org/learn/microbiome) and [An Introduction to Applied Bioinformatics](http://readIAB.org). (Disclaimer: I'm involved in both of those projects, but all content is free.)